# Error: cannot call methods on combobox prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that was functioning correctly in jQuery 1.7.2.

```
j$("#userIds").combobox('destroy');
j$("#userIds").combobox({});
```

but recently update jquery with 1.10.4 now, I receive the above error.

Any ideas? I appreciate any help on what this error message is and how to resolve it.

Comment: So where's the problem? Don't call methods on combobox prior to initialization

Comment: if i am not using j$("#userIds").combobox('destroy') and again initializing combobox using  j$("#userIds").combobox({}); than data is not load in combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jquery 3.3.1 and jquery ui 1.12. What I did is I initialize it first and clear the option.

```js
var cmbUserIds = $('#userIds');
cmbUserIds.combobox();
cmbUserIds.combobox('option', {});
```

Comment: Wrong use of snippet.Edit your answer and remove snippet please.